# What grants (revocations) would I need to prohibit updating of a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions, sql-grant

If I create a table with a normal user account:

```
create table test (a text, b text, c text);
```

The same user can perform all actions on the table...

```
john=# \z test
                            Access privileges
 Schema |   Name   | Type  | Access privileges | Column access privileges 
--------+----------+-------+-------------------+--------------------------
 public | testtest | table | john=ardDxt/john  |
```

Even if I run this:

```
revoke update on test from john;
```

The user can still update rows in the table. Can permissions be altered such that the user no longer has the grants that allow updating?

I've even tried this:

```
revoke all privileges on test from john;
```

And it empties out the john=ardDxt, but updates continue to work (assuming this is because john is also the owner of the database and/or table). I'm reading from the documentation itself where it says...

> PostgreSQL allows an object owner to revoke his own ordinary
>   privileges: for example, a table owner can make the table read-only to
>   himself by revoking his own INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and TRUNCATE
>   privileges.

But I don't seem to be able to do what it says, and the examples are rather sparse.

Comment: Can you please show the *full* DDL from the `CREATE TABLE` onward? Also `\d+` on the table and `\du+ john`.

Comment: As soon as you mentioned \du+ the solution was obvious. I use Postgres.app for development and its default user is also superuser. I created another superuser, revoked superuser for john, and then did the correct grant/revokes... I can set it so that the user can insert/delete but not update (or more specifically, can't update certain columns). You solved it, and if you want to write it up as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining for future visitors:

superusers ignore permission checks. This means that `GRANT` is unneccessary and `REVOKE` is ineffective.  Superusers can also disable triggers and much ore.  So you cannot fully prevent a superuser from updating the data.

If preventing updates is necessary, then your best bet is actually a trigger that raises an exception (or simply returns NULL, skipping the operation).  A superuser can still disable the trigger but it requires a little more effort.